# Apache log shows that the paho.mqtt.client is not present when called in php, but I can start the py script by ssh

Tags: php, python, apache

I have an easy Python script which publishes some MQTT static data for testing. This works fine when I call it in the terminal. Its an Ubuntu
18. But when I call the python script in my php with  `shell_exec("python mqttpub.py");` Apache2 log shows me `ImportError: No module named paho.mqtt.client`

I tried to exceute some other python scripts where I just return sys stat with `import sys` and that throws no error in the log and works.

**Python code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def main():    
    publishall()

def publishall():
    broker_address="localhost" 
    client = mqtt.Client("P1") #create new instance
    client.connect(broker_address) #connect to broker
    client.publish("sensor/temperature_celsius", "35")#publish

main()
```

**PHP Code: mqtt.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $action = $_POST['action'];

    switch ($action) {
        case "posttemp":
        posttemp();
            break;
    }   

    function posttemp () {
        $res = array();
        $res["resultmsg"] = "Temptest ok";
        $res["temp"] = $_POST['temp'];
        $output = shell_exec("python mqttpub.py");
        $res["py"] = $output;
        echo json_encode($res);
    }
?>
```

How can I solve this?